# how to override an extension view in RefineryCms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

I'm following the getting started project provided it for refineryCms for testing several things. Right now I want to override the events view. But I can not get the correct path for finding and overriding.

http://refinerycms.com/guides/getting-started#generating-an-extension

I'm trying

**rake refinery:override view=refinery/pages/events/show**

**rake refinery:override view=refinery/events/show**

***Couldn't match any view template files in any extensions like refinery/events/show***

and a lot of combinations but without luck.

What is the right form to find the view and override it??

Thanks

Edit: when I try to use the wildcards I got this error:

**zsh: no matches found: view=refinery/events/events/***

I had tried a lot of things, But I'm guessing, and I disliked that. there are some "formula" to get the correct path?

Thanks again

Comment: It's been forever since I have used refinery, and I keep remembering what I went through while trying to answer. So I keep editing. Try the third option in my answer.

Comment: just in case of zsh conflicts with rake: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-use-arguments-in-a-rake-task

Comment: This list has been indispensable for me while looking for overrides for refinerycms: https://gist.github.com/ryandeussing/2502881

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refinery extensions have their own view folder; so if you have events, it will put the view in /app/views/events. Have you tried with this wildcard '*' at the end, such as:

```
rake refinery:override view=refinery/events/*
```

You can override all views with

```
rake refinery:override view=refinery/*
```

Also, I had an extensions where it put the directory inside of a directory, so for example you can try to put two directories:

```
 rake refinery:override view=refinery/events/events/*
```

Comment: your last option worked, I must to scape the * character to avoid zsh conflicts rake refinery:override view=refinery/events/events/\\*
Thanks!!